# How to know when toast has finished displaying itslelf

Tags: java, android, layout, android-toast

I create a toast and display it. What i want is to display some text on screen once the toast has disappeared.

is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toast messages do not have any interfaces to tell you when they disapper, but their default length of how long they are displayed is known.

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

Use this to do the trick

```
private void doSometingAfterToast(int toastLength){
    new android.os.Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    }, toastLength);
}
```

Comment: so what would you suggest i do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607410/finish-activity-after-toast-message-disappears

Comment: Post delayed a runnable inside a handler. See my edit

Comment: Don't use new threads as suggested in the above post as you are changing UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is visible or not.

```
if (toast == null || toast.getView().getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    // Toast isn't shown //
}
```